# Using Forecasting for Daily Data

Tags: r, forecasting

Have used forecasting method using R. Using the below codes:

```
library(forecast)  
t1$StartDate <- as.Date(t1$StartDate, origin = "1899-12-30")  
## 10,1 indicates 10th Week & Sunday  
ordervalu_ts <- ts(t1$Revenue, start = c(10,1), frequency = 7)
print(ordervalu_ts)  
ordervalu_ts_decom <- HoltWinters(ordervalu_ts)  
print(ordervalu_ts_decom)  
ordervalu_ts_for <- forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters(ordervalu_ts_decom, h=30)  
print(ordervalu_ts_for)
```

`t1` is the input file. It has two columns: Date and Revenue. I am trying to forecast the Revenue for the next 30 days. ?Able to get output?. The date in the output is not in the right format. I have the following questions:

1. Start date: wanted to have it dynamic and not static (ie, the start date to take it form the column "Date"
2. Output is not providing me the exact date (providing 81.42857 instead of the first predicted date) while providing the prediction. Shows as "Below".

```
print(ordervalu_ts_for) 
         Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80       Lo 95    Hi 95  
81.42857      1390.4782  368.3917 2412.565 -172.668266 2953.625  
81.57143      1351.3890  328.9055 2373.872 -212.364558 2915.142  
81.71429      1355.7625  332.8507 2378.674 -208.646034 2920.171
```

Can some one help ? Have tried reviewing all the video's in youtube and online. Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you format your code a little nicer? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Xan, Thanks. Have formatted the codes to my best of my knowledge . I guess now it should be clear now. Thanks for your time

Comment: I edited for you and it was actually a little harder than usually :-) Have a look ,  basically you want to use the code block to get monospaced fonts or everything "cody" will look horrible. You can compare to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Also, you should find the suitable tags. That will increase your chance of getting help tremendously ;-)